# How can i make my code read specific line?

Tags: python

beginner in python here, probably asking simple question. Basically I got an assigment that sounds like this. Each line in a.txt represents a question to which responders could respond with a,b,c (1,2,3 to simplify). For example line 1 is: 1 2 1 1 3 3 . There are 3 questions(obv lines too). My assigment is to find out which answer is the most common for every question. I wanted to make my code universal - a.txt can be modified with additional questions and answers. So far I got this:

```
for l in range(sum(1 for line in open('a.txt'))):
  a, b, c = 0, 0 ,0
  with open("a.txt") as subor:
    o=[int(i) for i in subor.readline().split()]
    for k in range(len(o)):
      if o[k] == 3:
       c = c+1
      elif o[k] == 1:
        a = a + 1
      else:
        b = b + 1
    if a > b and a > c:
      print("In question", l + 1 ,'is answer A the most common one')
    elif c > b and c > c:
      print("In question", l + 1 ,'is answer C the most common one')
    elif a == b or a == c:
      print("Cannot be decided")
    else:
      print("In question", l + 1 ,'is answer B the most common one')
    a, b, c = 0, 0 ,0
    o.clear()
```

The code works, but it only finds the most common answer for the 1st question, it never moves to the next one. How can i modify this code to move to the next question?

Comment: Hum! the condition `c > c` is always False (see the line: `elif c > b and c > c:`).

Comment: An additional tip for readability: make your variables long. There's no need to use one character variables anymore, instead, try naming them things like `answers_a`, `answers_b`, `answer_line`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop every time you execute line `with open("a.txt") as subor:` you open again the file. So you read the first line of the file with `subor.readline()`, then you re-open the file in the next iteration of the for loop. There are some errors also in the following part, I fixed them for you:

```
with open("a.txt") as subor:
    lines = subor.read().splitlines()

    l = 0
    for line in lines:

        o = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
        a = len([x for x in o if x == 1])
        b = len([x for x in o if x == 2])
        c = len([x for x in o if x == 3])

        if a > b and a > c:
            print("In question {} is answer A the most common one".format(l + 1))
        elif b > a and b > c:
            print("In question {} is answer B the most common one".format(l + 1))
        elif c > a and c > b:
            print("In question {} is answer C the most common one".format(l + 1))
        else:
            print("Question {} cannot be decided".format(l + 1))

        l += 1
```